# Option clash for package moderncvskillmatrix (moderncv)

Tags: moderncv

Since the last update of `moderncv` package I can't compile my CV anymore. It has worked for years before.

There seems to be an option clash. Here's a short version of what I am talking about:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[left,norules]{banking}
\moderncvbody{1} % classic

\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Mustermann}
\address{}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{My professions}
\cvline{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If yes, what is the exact text of the error?

Comment: I get  `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package moderncvskillmatrix.` @Marijn

Comment: Yes, that's the error I get. So how can I fix this? It was always working before with the same template.

Comment: What's strange is that I still get a PDF output, but I can't see anything when I compile it.

Answer (score 2):

With the current version 2.1.0 of class `moderncv` was a new package added to all `moderncvbodyx.sty` files (with x from i to vi). This new package `moderncvskillmatrix` calls options like `moderncvbodyi` to know where it comes from.

Calling `\moderncvstyle[left, norules]{banking}` calls internal `moderncvbodyiii` which calls `moderncvskillmatrix` with option `moderncvbodyiii` resulting later in the error message ...

Calling `\moderncvbody{1}` to get the layout of the body from style `classic` itself calls package `moderncvskillmatrix` with option `moderncvbodyi`. Now you have the option clash, same package called with two different options ...

To get what you want, the header of style `banking` and the body of style `classic` you can omit calling style `banking`. Call instead simply `\moderncvhead{3}` to get the same result.

So with the following MWE (important code changes marked with `<=========`)

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

%\moderncvstyle[left, norules]{banking} % 
\moderncvhead{3} % banking <============================================
\moderncvbody{1} % classic

\name{Max}{Mustermann} % <==============================================
\address{test}{address}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}} % <========================================
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Achievement 1
\item Achievement 2 (with sub-achievements)
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3
\item Achievement 4
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2\newline{}}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that I changed depreciated commands of class `moderncv` to the new ones ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a very usefull help here :
https://nuanceabounds.org/fix-latex-package-option-clash-error-passoptionstopackage/
which basically made me add
`\PassOptionsToPackage{moderncvbodyiii,moderncvbodyi}{moderncvskillmatrix}`
at the very beginning of my tex document.
Now it works perfectly :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works.